# storing scraped table using rvest in to a variable

Tags: r, rvest

how do I store the output I get from  html_table into a variable?:

```
  library(rvest)


   elec<- 
   read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botswana_general_election,_1969")

    elec%>%

   html_nodes("table.wikitable")%>% 
   html_table(fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: try: html_table(fill=TRUE) - >variable

Answer (score 1):

Minimal example:

```
library(rvest)

    data <- read_xml("url")


    a <- data %>% xml_find_all("//node a") %>% xml_text() 
    b <- data %>% xml_find_all("//node b") %>% xml_text()

    df =  data.frame(a,b)
```