# Retrieving data from large xml file using node path in R

Tags: r, xml

I am new to xml, and many xml nodes I found are not the same as my file. I want to extract data from large xml file using R (dummy xml file is below). I know even though R has memory limitation, extract specific nodes from large xml file is possible using xmlEventParse() from r XML package. properly naming file path to reach my target data. My final output in form of dataframe should have columns that reflects these nodes N9:Shareholder,  N5:IdentifierElement, N2:NameElement. Thanks for your help.

XML code

        
          
            [FOO LIMITED
          
          
            
              120801
              
                Companies Register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNCaR.png)

Comment: Maybe my answer to a similar question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242428/storing-scraped-table-using-rvest-in-to-a-variable/46242579#46242579

Comment: Many thanks Edu. The problem  that read_xml() chops off my 32GB RAM. I then used tried to use getNodeSet() to target specific node but it returns empty list. Here is my dummy code: